# How to manipulate a cell based upon two other conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
if chapa['Service Type'] == 'Managed Services' and chapa['Term'] == 12:
chapa['payout'] * 10000

else:
     pass
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I am trying to change a cell (payout) based upon the conditions within its row. Not sure what the best way to do this in Pandas is. It must only be effected by its specific row.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: `chapa.loc[(chapa['Service Type'] == 'Managed Services') & (chapa['Term'] == 12), 'payout'] *= 1000`

Comment: @mozway I get the invalid syntax when I try to use this. Any idea why? it has a problem with the *=

Comment: @mcccc I double checked, the syntax is valid and the command works. Please provide a fully reproducible example in your question. Note that the above code replaces the loop completely.